# Is there a way to silently run a bash command after a file save in vim?

Tags: vim

Right now I'm using the following command to compile a coffeescript file each time I save:

```
au BufWritePost widget.coffee ! ./compile_widget.sh
```

However each time I save I'm asked the following:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Is there any way I can save and not have to hit enter to continue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using something like [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic).

To address the explicit question however, you would need to do

```
au BufWritePost widget.coffee silent !./compile_widget.sh | redraw
```

The prompt is triggered by the output from the command.  The `silent` suppresses the prompt, but when you do that then Vim doesn't redraw the screen after the shell command so that you're able to see the output from the command.  So, the `| redraw` forces Vim to redraw the screen.

This is discussed at [:help :!](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd)

Comment: I ended up using without the redraw because I don't refresh anything on the screen (compile_widget.sh just compiles the file elsewhere).  Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You shouldn't ask Vim to do that. You should look into [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), [watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr) or other tools that look at the disk and to their thing.

Comment: Watchr was being a bit slow and I was frustrated to not see my changes immediately in IE. But you are certainly right.  This kind of thing should be done with a tool like this one.  It's just that my setup was too slow to work right now.